# Increase width of columns on different sheets in excel using pandas and xlsxwriter

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write data in different sheets of excel file using `pandas` and `xlsxwriter`. My code is as following.

```
import pandas as pd


# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [111231231, 123243244, 131231231, 142131231]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [211232131, 2212312322, 2323212213, 2412312312]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [31123123311, 32345225245, 332542355432, 342435245245]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

I am printing all the dataframes on different sheets and want to set the width of the columns a bit more.

I read the documentation and the commands `writer.set_column()` are not working for me. I would be grateful if someone helps me in this regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try like following. As an example, I only set column_width for 'Sheet1'.
You can try for other Sheet if needed. Also, I intended to set one column via 'idx' so you can specify which column to change width. In your case, it doesnt matter as there is only one column, but in case you might have serveral ones.
Kr.

```
import pandas as pd


# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [111231231, 123243244, 131231231, 142131231]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [211232131, 2212312322, 2323212213, 2412312312]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [31123123311, 32345225245, 332542355432, 342435245245]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')

# set column width for 'Sheet1'. If need do the same for other Sheet 
column_width = 30
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
idx = 1
worksheet.set_column(idx, idx, column_width)
    
    
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```